# What is the main purpose of MTU in Bluetooth BREDR

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

As much I understood
MTU is the maximum transmission unit, which specifies the Maximum size of the SDU packet.
I need more relevant information about MTU.
Please guide me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have any specific questions about the MTU? Do you want to know the min and max values? It's hard to answer without more details

Comment: I just wanted to know what role does MTU plays in L2CAP

Comment: Maybe this article answers your questions: https://punchthrough.com/maximizing-ble-throughput-part-2-use-larger-att-mtu-2/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.